# Why can't I make this number an integer?

Tags: python

I need to compare 2 values: the first variable in a list and the user's input. The user's input is already an integer but the code won't let me convert the other value into integer form.

I've tried "int", "float" and "complex" just to see, but without success.

Here's my code:

```
Stock = open("stock.txt","r")
Next = False
print("Products avaliable are: ")
for loop in range (10):
    StockProduct = Stock.readline()
    product = StockProduct.split("\t")
    print(product[0] , product[1])
while Next != True:
    USERproduct = int(input("Which product did you buy? "))
    Amount = int(input("How many did you buy? "))
    for loop in range (10):
        StockProduct = Stock.readline()
        product = StockProduct.split("\t")
        productONE = product[0]

        if USERproduct == int(productONE) :
            USER2 == product
            print(USER2)
            Next = True
        else:
           USERproduct = int(input(" 2 Which product did you buy? "))
         #   Amount = int(input("2 How many did you buy? "))
```

and the output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Task 3.py", line 20, in <module>
    if USERproduct == int(productONE) :
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
>>>
```

This is for a controlled assessment at school.

Comment: You have a line that starts with a tab character. When you split that line on a tab delimiter, the first element is an empty string, which isn't a number.

Comment: Just before the bad line, add `print(product)`. You may get several good prints before the one that crashes the program. But look at the first element of the bad one and then its obvious which line in the input text is bad. You could try to detect the bad line - but it is also legitimate to crash here if your program requires strictly valid input. Python, for instance, doesn't try to fix up bad lines you type in, it raises a syntax error.

Comment: How big is your input file? `readline()` returns an empty string when it reaches the end of file. And splitting an empty string ends up with `['']` which looks a lot like your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can get your program working with two changes. First, instead of limiting reads to 10 lines, just iterate through the file. Second, once you've gone to through the file, you either need to rewind it back to the start or reopen it.

```
Stock = open("stock.txt","r")
Next = False
print("Products avaliable are: ")
for StockProduct in Stock:
    product = StockProduct.split("\t")
    print(product[0] , product[1])
while Next != True:
    USERproduct = int(input("Which product did you buy? "))
    Amount = int(input("How many did you buy? "))
    Stock.seek(0)
    for StockProduct in Stock:
        product = StockProduct.split("\t")
        productONE = product[0]

        if USERproduct == int(productONE) :
            USER2 == product
            print(USER2)
            Next = True
        else:
           USERproduct = int(input(" 2 Which product did you buy? "))
         #   Amount = int(input("2 How many did you buy? "))
```